# finding matching values in two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, compare

So I have this value I am getting back from an API that could either be a single item or multiple items.

I map over and return the value I want.

```
const value = JSONObject.map(data => {return data.value});

console.log(value); // ["value"]
```

or multiple strings if more than one value present in the map.

Now comes the part where I am confused.

I have another local JSON Object that I want to match against the value from the api.

```
for(i = 0; i < LocalJSONObject; i++;){
 if(value === LocalJSONObject[i].value){
 console.log("matching values")
 }
}
```

Only thing is "value" is an array that can contain one single string item or multiple string items.

My understanding is the above if statement is comparing an array to a string which would never be true and thus it never logs.

How do I get it to compare the value in the value array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var lo = 0; lo < LocalJSONObject.length; ++lo) {
  for (var va = 0; va < value.length; ++va) {
    if (value[va] === LocalJSONObject[lo].value) {
      console.log('Matching values:', value[va]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is giving me the desired outcome. I wonder if Underscore.JS has a method for this to make the code a little cleaner?

Comment: @AlexanderMcComb, it's clean enough for me, two nested loops... I don't know about Underscore, but I wouldn't mind, it's a very common construction. The important thing is paying attention to the index names... if you just name them `i` and `j` (like many people do), it's harder to follow and more error-prone; using `lo` and `va` is easier on the eyes, closer to the variable names they are used into.

Comment: I just think I have read some where that nested for loops are usually a bad idea. But thank you for giving me an answer that actually works! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct in assuming that your statement is comparing an array to a string because the `map` method returns an array.

To solve it efficiently, you can use the [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to get the result.

```
for(i = 0; i < LocalJSONObject; i++;){
 if(value.includes(LocalJSONObject[i].value)){
   console.log("matching values")
 }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, didnt think includes did what I was trying. I will let you know!

Comment: This works exactly the same and arguably might be faster. +1 for the help!